# Why Pivot chart is comig as a straight line when using Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly

I need to plot a pivot chart from a multi-indexed pivot table.  This is my pivot table description "**multi_index = pd.pivot_table(df_new, index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp' ,'Supply'],columns = 'Frequency', values = 'NoiseLevel',)"**

I used Plotly at that time it is coming as a single straight line. I am expecting two zig-zag lines one for frequency 0.8 and the other for 1.6 as shown in the first figure. could you please tell me where I went wrong? please see my code below. I don't know where I need to put the **"columns = 'Frequency'"** I think it needs to come at Y axis.
Please see my dta frame below(Pivot Table)

```
Frequency                  0.8     1.6
Device_ID Temp  Supply                
FF_2649   -40.0 1.65   -100.72 -101.35
                1.71   -100.61 -101.74
                1.80   -100.74 -101.64
                1.89   -100.63 -101.69
                3.60   -100.60 -101.46
...                        ...     ...
TT_2441    85.0 1.65    -94.99  -94.97
                1.71    -94.85  -95.24
                1.80    -95.02  -94.97
                1.89    -94.69  -96.20
                3.60    -94.90  -94.91


data=[go.Scatter(
x=multi_index.index,
y=multi_index.values,
mode='lines',
name='Noise Level'
)]
layout=go.Layout(title='Noise Level')
figure=go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
pyo.plot(figure)
```

[image: Expected ouput]

[image: Output Obtained after running plotly code]

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: Updated my question. Please let me know if it is fine or not.

Comment: @HARITO typically for questions that involve data visualization, a sample of your DataFrame will help people answer your question. can you include `multi_index.head()` or a sample DataFrame that is similar to multi_index in your question?

Comment: I have added my data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **plotly** does not directly support multi-index
- concat values in multi-index to a string that identifies it
- generate a **plotly scatter** per column

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(""" Device_ID Temp  Supply                 0.8     1.6
FF_2649   -40.0 1.65   -100.72 -101.35
- -               1.71   -100.61 -101.74
- -                1.80   -100.74 -101.64
- -                1.89   -100.63 -101.69
- -                3.60   -100.60 -101.46
TT_2441    85.0 1.65    -94.99  -94.97
- -                1.71    -94.85  -95.24
- -                1.80    -95.02  -94.97
- -                1.89    -94.69  -96.20
- -                3.60    -94.90  -94.91"""), sep="\s+").replace({"-":np.nan}).fillna(method="ffill").apply(pd.to_numeric, **{"errors":"ignore"}).set_index(["Device_ID","Temp","Supply"])

# generate a line for each column dataframe.  concat values of multi-index to make it work with plotly
data = [go.Scatter(x=pd.Series(df.index.values).apply(lambda i: " ".join(map(str, i))), y=df[c], 
                   mode='lines', name=f'Noise Level {c}')
 for c in df.columns]
layout=go.Layout(title='Noise Level') 
figure=go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout) 
figure
```

[image]